# Fourier transformation of rational function

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

Given $f(y)= \frac{y}{y^2+2y+2}$

calulate $ \hat f(\omega)=\int_\mathbb{R} f(y) \exp(-iy\omega)$

I know that $\mathcal F\{\exp(-|x|)\}=\frac{1}{1^2+\omega^2}$,
via Transformation $y=x-1$

$\frac{y}{y^2+2y+2} = \frac{x-1}{x^2+1}= \frac{x}{x^2+1}+\frac{-1}{x^2+1}
= \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{2} \ln(x^2+1)+ \frac{-1}{x^2+1} $
, but I can't integrate the last term. I am very thankful for hints.

Greetings.

Comment: You already know that $\mathcal F\{\exp(-|x|)\}=\frac{1}{1+\omega^2}$. Then, by the formula $\mathcal F^2\{f(x)\} = 2\pi \, f(-x)$ you have
$$\mathcal F\left\{ \frac{1}{1+x^2} \right\} = \mathcal F^2\{ \exp(-|x|) \} = 2\pi \, \exp(-|x|)$$

Comment: Thanky you. I know that. My main problem is the $ln(x^2+1)$ part.

Comment: You wrote "the last term".

Answer (score 3):

$$f(y)=\frac{y}{y^{2}+2y+2}=\frac{y}{(y+1-i)(y+1+i)}=\frac{1+i}{2(y+1-i)}+\frac{1-i}{2((y+1+i))}$$
Then
$$\mathcal{F}[f(y)](\omega)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(y)e^{-i\omega{y}}dy=$$
$$=\frac{1+i}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{-i\omega{y}}}{(y+1-i)}dy+\frac{1-i}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{-i\omega{y}}}{(y+1+i)}dy$$
The first integrand has a pole at $y=-1+i$, so we intend an infinite semicircular contour in the upper half plane and the second integrand has a pole at $y=-1-i$, so we intend an infinite semicircular contour in the lower half plane
The residue at the pole of the first integran is
$$e^{(i+1)\omega}$$
The residue at the pole of the second integran is
$$e^{(i-1)\omega}$$
Thus
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{-i\omega{y}}}{(y+1-i)}dy=2\pi{i}e^{(i+1)\omega}$$
and
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{-i\omega{y}}}{(y+1-i)}dy=2\pi{i}e^{(i-1)\omega}$$
So
$$\mathcal{F}[f(y)](\omega)=\pi(i-1)e^{(i+1)\omega}+\pi(i+1)e^{(i-1)\omega}=2\pi{e^{i\omega}}\Big(i\cosh{\omega}-\sinh\omega\Big)$$

Comment: seems very elegant. How do exactly know that the residue at the pole is $e^{(i \pm 1)\omega}$?

Comment: Are you sure that the result is correct, Kiryl?

Comment: should be... if some mistakes will be found, I'll be happy to edit the answer.

Comment: and you find the residue of $f(z)$ at $z=c$, say by the formula $Res(f(z), z=c)=\lim_{z\rightarrow{c}}(z-c)f(z)$